# A general method for solving systems of quadratic equations

Tags: reference-request, systems-of-equations, quadratics, book-recommendation

For linear systems we have general methods (i.e. Gauss elimination). Is there a general method for solving systems of quadratic equations with many variables? I heard about Groebner bases; is there another methods? Can you advise me some books or papers?

Comment: Numerical solutions or exact solutions?  I used to solve such systems numerically with up to 100 or so equations with Newton's method.  But I was lucky to have a good starting point.

Comment: @jbuddenh, exact solutions, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buchberger's algorithm is the most important method, I think. This amounts to computing a Gröbner basis. In some cases, however, one can do better (the complexity of Buchberger's algorithm is double exponential, hence very bad).
A standard reference is the book of Bernd Sturmfels, [Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf). Here are several other methods given, i.e.,from tropical algebraic geometry.

Remark: The restriction that all polynomial are quadratic is not really a simplification.

Comment: It's very surprising (it's about remark). I specifically mentioned the Gröbner to get a reference to some special techniques. Can you please explain in a simple way why this is so?

Comment: Degrees of resultants etc. are already growing very quickly for systems of quadratic equations.

Comment: Is it really not any easier to solve quadratic systems than general systems?

Comment: @user76284 No, see Sturmfels' book. Here is a toy example. Take two quadratic equations in $x$ and $y$, say, $y^2+2xy+3y+4=0$ and $x^2+3xy+7=0$. The first equation gives $x= -1/(2y)(y^2 + 3y + 4)$, since $y\neq 0$ by the equation, but then the second equation becomes $- 5y^4 - 12y^3 + 21y^2 + 24y + 16=0$. So degree's anyway become higher quickly, even if you start with quadratic ones.